# Excel: How to halt calculations until all connections have been refreshed?

Tags: excel

**The question:**

In an Excel workbook I've got about 50 connections to external sources (csv files). Every time I refres the connections, the entire workbook is bein recalculated. Is there a way to halt all calculations until all connections have been refreshed? Menu option? VBA script?

**The details:**

I thought something as simple as this would be the trick:

```
Sub RefreshAll()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

However, this does not seem to be deactivating spreadsheet calculations between loading each connection as I had hoped. Any suggestions?

Comment: it should. where is your macro placed. What does the rest of your macro do?

Comment: It's placed in a module. All the macro does is what you see in the snippet above.

Comment: Does [ Formulas > Calculation Opiton > Manual ] helps? || When selected, it halts all defined calculation, you may press F9 to start calculations.